Валидация номера телефона в Python
Надо выдать True когда город москва и номер из 10 чисел и начинается с 7 или 8
Сейчас выдаёт только False
В чём именно ошибка и как исправить?
applications = [
         'name=Аня,phone=8800234 ,city=москва',
         'name=КОЛЯ,phone=8800900871 ,city=МОСКВА',
         'name=Валентина,phone=7950900871 ,city=волгоград',
         'name=,phone=7999901871,city=москва',
         'name=Иван,phone=7999901871,city=москва',
         'name=Инга,phone=,city=москва'

] 
# функция проверки валидности номера
def check_phone(phone):
  #Ваш код здесь   
        if (phone[0]=='8' or phone[0]=='7') and phone[9].isnumeric():
            return True
        else:
            return False
# функция проверки города
def check_city(city):
  #Ваш код здесь
        if city == 'москва':
            return True
        else:
            return False
# функция проверки одной анкеты
def check_application(application):
  #Ваш код здесь
    normalized_string = application.lower()
    normalized_string = normalized_string[normalized_string.find('p')::]
    city = normalized_string[normalized_string.find('city=')+5:-1]
    phone = application[application.find('phone=')+6:application.find('phone=')+16]
    if check_city(city) and check_phone(phone) == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
# функция проверки списка анкет
def find_valid_applications(applications):
  #Ваш код здесь
    for i in range(len(applications)):
        print(f'{applications[i]} --- {check_application(applications[i])}')


int(phone[9]) == int - непонятно чего вы хотели этим добиться, но число никогда не будет равно типу

убедится что там число а не буква, но я вас поняла

(type(int(phone[9])) == int)

int(...) возвращает всегда число, быть здесь буквы не может в принципе никак. А если внутри phone[9] окажется буква, то int(phone[9]) просто выкинет ошибку

так лучше??????

Теперь наоборот условие type(int(phone[9])) == int всегда истинно, потому что, как я отметил выше, int(...) это всегда число

Это условие лишнее, если phone — всегда число. Всё равно, что написать просто true. UPD. В ответах вам уже привели верное условие

Проще использвать phone[9].isnumeric()

спасибо, это исправила, но проблема на месте

Можете привести обновленный код, может там опечатка какая..

@Rijen, "Проще использвать phone[9].isnumeric()" — да, так проще, но это никак не решает проблему условия, описанную в тексте вопроса. Потому что должна проверяться длина номера, а не его тип

Проблема в check_city, минутку, вкурю как оно разбирается. Там получается "москв"

@Chaos_Sower Ну, про длину я ответил в ответе, а тут вот разбираем детали )

я нашла ошибку в check_application, сейчас посмотрю как исправить

Надо узнать, какие именно проверки выдают false — первая, вторая или все? Я так подразумеваю, что все. Тогда 1) Исправляете первое условие на if len(phone) == 10 and (phone[0]=='8' or phone[0]=='7'):, 2) Исправляете второе условие на то, которое не будет учитывать регистр (.lower())

а, нет, показалось(((

Во первых, сделайте нормальный разбор, так как у вас есть ключи, по которым можно делить
app_dict = dict(x.split("=") for x in normalized_string.split(","))
И передайте значения по ключам в обработчик, желательно раздельно, чтобы упростить отладку.
if check_city(app_dict["city"]) == false print ("Ваш город - оцтой")

Насколько я понимаю, проблема заключалась в том, что в функции check_phone() вы проверяете, что первое число должно начинаться с 8 или с 7, а затем вы зачем-то проверяете, что последнее число должно быть равно типу.
Если исходить из вашего описания, вам нужно проверить длину, тогда для того будет использоваться функция len(), таким образом, исправленный код функции будет выглядеть так:
def check_phone(phone):
    if len(phone) == 10 and (phone[0]=='8' or phone[0]=='7'):
        return True
    return False


int(phone[9])==int Тут вы выбираете 9 символ из строки с номером, и сравниваете его с типом.
Для того чтобы узнать длину номера, используйте сравнение len(phone)==10.
Для того чтобы убедиться, что это число используйте phone.isnumeric().

applications = [
         'name=Аня,phone=8800234 ,city=москва',
         'name=КОЛЯ,phone=8800900871 ,city=МОСКВА',
         'name=Валентина,phone=7950900871 ,city=волгоград',
         'name=,phone=7999901871,city=москва',
         'name=Иван,phone=7999901871,city=москва',
         'name=Инга,phone=,city=москва'

] 
# функция проверки валидности номера
def check_phone(phone):
        
        if len(phone)>0 and (phone[0]=='8' or phone[0]=='7') and phone.isnumeric() and len(phone)==10:
            return True
        else:
            return False
# функция проверки города
def check_city(city):
        if len(city)>0 and city == 'москва':
            return True
        else:
            return False
# функция проверки одной анкеты
def check_application(application):
  #Ваш код здесь
    normalized_string = application.lower()
    app_dict = dict(x.split("=") for x in normalized_string.split(","))
    print (app_dict)
   
    if check_city(app_dict["city"].strip()) and check_phone(app_dict["phone"].strip()) == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
# функция проверки списка анкет
def find_valid_applications(applications):
    for i in range(len(applications)):
        print(f'{applications[i]} --- {check_application(applications[i])}')


find_valid_applications(applications)


Вот это phone[-1].isnumeric() зачем?

спасибо, работает)))

@Chaos_Sower Не знаю )

Нейросетевым написанием занимаетесь?!

а, нет. ошибку выдаёт

IndexError: string index out of range

@Chaos_Sower Нет, ручками пишу. По комментам понятно, что зачем-то хочет проверить последний символ на число )

Обновил, добавил проверку нулевой длинны.

теперь всё чисто)

Да, вместо phone[-1].isnumeric() достаточно просто phone.isnumeric()

Зачем проверять phone на тип int...? Разве это может быть чем-то другим?

Вы что, реально назвали своего сына Роберт'); DROP TABLE Students; --? XD

А теперь - regexp!

def check_phone(phone):         return not re.search("^(7|8)\d{9}$",phone)==None

@Chaos_Sower, увы я слишком туп для нейросети. И вообще, мне кажется, подобный оффтоп тут не привествуется.

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.
